# Automatically cross-reference a word in a call

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Need a formula for Excel to check for a word in the cell next to it so it will insert a price from elsewhere on the sheet

Left side showing companies and right side being the price

[image]

I have previously used

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$P$97,"Alliance",$D$2:$D$100:$L$2:$L$81)
```

but this required too much manual input the more companies are added, is there a formula/word where it will just auto check for the word in the cell next to it?

The cell references are for where the companies and prices are on the rest of the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're missing context (of the rest of the sheet and where this formula is going to be) but in principle it seems that what your asking is simply to have the cell reference instead of the word.

So simply put the cell reference instead of the word... Like this (if the formula goes in `B2` and *ALLIANCE* is in `A2':

`=SUMIF($C$2:$P$97,A2,$D$2:$D$100:$L$2:$L$81)`

Comment: Ah it was something simple, I thank you for your help again :)